# Repeated Mixed model for circular data or mixed model of circular data

Tags: r

I want to do a repeated measure ANOVA for circular data, but I have  not found a good example except for Watson-Williams test (ANOVA equivalent), but I don't think it accounts for repeated measures. Then I tried to fit a mixed model using `bpnreg` package (https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.02040/full) which uses cognitive data for modelling mixed model. I do not know why I can't run this; it keeps giving error on my data. My data is means of three variables of 10 different cities for different years from 2000-2017. I want to see if the Mean of one variable is dependent on others and has interaction among variables and among cities and years. This model does not take categorical data such as name of cities so I coded cities as a number (not sure if it is a right approach), let me know if any one knows.
Following is my data and code. Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my data format for 10 different cities.

```
Cities   Year   MeanP     MeanE      MeanG      Subject
CityA    2000   158.1235  158.1415   158.1512   1
CityA    2005   158.1735  158.1215   158.1912   1
CityA    2010   158.1035  158.1615   158.1112   1
CityA    2015   158.1935  158.1215   158.1012   1
CityA    2017   158.1335  158.1715   158.1312   1
CityB    2000   154.2347  154.2567   154.2744   2
```

My code is as follows

```
library(bpnreg)
data<- read.table("meanscities.csv", header = T, sep=",")
modelfit <- bpnme(MeanG ~ MeanP + MeanE + (1|Subject),
                  data = data,
                  its = 10000, burn = 1000, n.lag = 3, seed = 101)
```

Following is the error:

> Error in mmme(pred.I, data, pred.II) :
> Not all nesting variables are class numeric.

But the data is in a list format and all numeric except for name of city.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons that make no sense to me (because I haven't read the paper), apparently your "nesting variable" (`Subject`) needs to be *numeric* specifically - and being an integer type doesn't qualify!

```
data$Subject <- as.numeric(dd$Subject)
```

gets me past this error.  Unfortunately I get another error that's harder to figure out, but hopefully it's just because I was using the trivial bit of data set you posted above ...

In addition:

- your response variable **must be in radians**, otherwise your answers will likely make no sense ...
- are you sure `bpnme` doesn't allow categorical predictors? Coding a categorical predictor as an integer makes almost no sense. If `bpnme` doesn't allow it and you really need them you can create your own dummy variables ...